# do not change directory if gitbash is started by docker quickstart terminal shortcut

Tags: docker, windows-10, git-bash

The Docker Quickstart Terminal loads gitbash with the following flags:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh"
```

My standard gitbash shortcut is defined as:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" --cd-to-home
```

I believe the problem is in my .bashrc file where I change the directory to the current project I'm working on.

The issue seems to be this directory change causes start.sh to begin from an unexpected location, causing an initialization crash.  Is there a general solution to running gitbash in multiple contexts? (e.g. is there a way to detect flags like login or if a script is being called after startup that I could use to avoid changing directories?)